# Creating a list in JavaScript from django variable is autoparsing strings as dates

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm working in a django project and I'm sending a dataframe with "to_dict" to the template. The dataframe consist of dates and extra info that I deleted for ease of understanding.

Im using that data in javascript, but I need the date as a string as the lib I'm using doesn't support date objects for some reason.

The problem comes that when I make a list out of the parameter the dates get parsed automatically without me doing anything extra.

So for this lines of code:

```
listData = {{data|safe}};
console.log({{data|safe}});
console.log(listData);
```

I get this result:

[image: problem screenshot]

So what i need is that creating a list doesn't parse the string to date and if possible the reason why is this happening.